# How to disable JSF components programmatically

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

We have a JSF application with `<rich:tab>` which shows fields depending of some configuration stored in a database, so the components are not defined in the .xhtml page but have to be generated programmatically such in this example:

[image: Example of dinamically generated fields]

Components are generated in a panel:

```
<rich:tab id="someTab" header="#{msg['someHeader']}" immediate="true">
    <rich:messages/>
    <h:panelGrid id="generatedComponentsContainer"/>
</rich:tab>
```

Component generation example (simplified for simplicity):

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
UIPanel panel = (UIPanel) ctx.getViewRoot().findComponent("someForm:generatedComponentsContainer");

text = (UIInput) ctx.getApplication().createComponent(ctx, "javax.faces.Input", "javax.faces.component.UIInput");
text.getAttributes().put("label", someLabel);
panel.getChildren().add(text);
```

Those components have to be shown disabled depending on some condition, so I used the following code to disable each of them if needed:

```
if (!showEnabled) { text.getAttributes().put("disabled", "true"); }
```

This method works for `UIInput` and `HtmlInputTextarea` but it is not working for `UICalendar`, throwing a `IllegalArgumentException (argument type mismatch)`.

How can I disable the calendar?

I have been also wondering if this code just disables the component at the client side leaving it enabled at the server. This would probably be a security threat as somebody could enable a component via Javascript and submit the form to the server. I am not sure about this being possible, please advise if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I noticed there are some classes that extend the ones we were using in our project. Those classes have a getter/setter for the disabled attribute which also disables the component in the server side. I tested this disabling the components programmatically and removing the disabled attribute while browsing the page to allow edition and submit. When submitting the form, the values are setted in the request but ignored at the server side. Bean values remain unaltered.

The classes we have used:

`HtmlInputTextarea` instead of `UIInput`

`HtmlInputText` instead of `UIInput`

We were already using `UICalendar`, which fits the purpose

A sample of code:

```
HtmlInputText text = (HtmlInputText) ctx.getApplication().createComponent(
ctx, HtmlInputText.COMPONENT_TYPE, "javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText");

if (!showEnabled) { text.setDisabled(true); }
```

When debugging the contents of the `HtmlInputText` you can see a `ComponentStateHelper` object (named `stateHelper`) which stores the disabled state of the component (among other data). Its superinterface is `StateHolder`:

> ```
> public interface StateHolder
> ```
>
> This interface is implemented by classes that need to save their state
>   between requests.

I understand that server-side state of the component is stored in this object, but I am not sure whether it is stored only here or in more points, or even if my interpretation of its purpose is correct. Feedback from an expert would be very useful.